# Can I attach my mosaic tiles to wall in stages?

Tags: kitchens, tile, backsplash

I am doing a tile backsplash in the kitchen and I am not able to adhere all of the tiles at the same time. Can I do the adhering in stages as long as I don't leave any excess adhesive on the wall before returning to continue at a later date?

FYI once all the tile is up I plan to grout everything at the same time.

Comment: How are you adhering the mosaics and what exactly are they sticking to?

Comment: I am using a tile adhesive called AcrylPro to attach my tiles to the existing painted drywall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, installing tile piecemeal is perfectly acceptable. And,as you noted, the only precaution to take before you stop for the day is to clean the leading edges of the last tile of any thinset or mastic.And you are also correct by grouting all the tile in one application.

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the time you want as long as it is kept clean. But the grout needs to be put on as you have suggested or it will show differences in color.